# TWebBrowser and ProcessMessages

Tags: delphi, c++builder, twebbrowser

Sample code for working with TWebBrowser typically inserts a loop to call `Application.ProcessMessages` until `ReadyState` is `READYSTATE_LOADED`.

For example, from the [Embarcadero forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=869921#869921), some code to load an HTML string into a TWebBrowser:

```
mWebBrowser->Navigate(L"about:blank");
while (mWebBrowser->ReadyState< READYSTATE_LOADED)
   Application->ProcessMessages();

// load mWebBrowser from TStreamAdapter
```

As I understand it, calling ProcessMessages is risky, because it can create reentrancy problems.  (For example, if the user clicks the Close button on the form, then that message could get handled by ProcessMessages, such that the TWebBrowser instance no longer even exists when the function returns.)

Am I understanding this correctly?

If so, is there a "safe" way to handle TWebBrowser's needs to have messages processed, without ProcessMessages' risks?  Or do I need to redesign all of my TWebBrowser code to be asynchronous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to call `ProcessMessages` at all. You can let the main application message loop deal with the messages.

But the code here is waiting for a page to load before doing the next task. To retain that sort of behaviour you switch to an asynchronous event driven approach. Remove the loop and instead handle the browser's `OnDocumentComplete` event. Only then do you load the actual content from your stream.

Comment: So I'm correct in thinking that, if I want to do one thing (set a blank page) and then the next, it's not safe to rely on ProcessMessages?

Comment: Also, is there a more appropriate event handler to use? Example code waits for `READYSTATE_LOADED`, which presumably happens before `OnDocumentComplete` and `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`. (In practice, especially when navigating to `about:blank`, I suspect there's little or no difference.)

Comment: It's plausible that I've got the wrong event for this specific example, but the concept is sound. Switch to an event driven design.